# How to update global variable on a successful event from inside a function (polling)?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, polling

```
<script>

var status = {{ check_status }};

call_polling = function() {
    // polling request to API (async)
    success:function(result){
        status = result.check_status;
    }

}


if(status) {
    var timer = setInterval(function() { call_polling(); }, 2000);
}
else{
clearInterval(function(){ call_polling();});
}
</script>
```

So, I have a code with Async request to see the status of a backend process. So, first I set `status` to 1 (i.e check_status via context in Django). So, if `status` is 1 then `var timer` line will start calling `call_polling()` function every 2 seconds
So, `call_polling()` will query the API to check the status and on a successful response like `{'check_status': 1}` it will transfer the `status = 1`. Indicating the backend process is still running. Once, the backend process is done, I pass the JSON response as `{'check_status' : 0}` which
should be `status=0` and then it will not go into `if` but instead clear the polling Interval (as we know the background processing is already finished) and async call to API Should stop.

But it doesn't works, and the javascript still makes call_polling() to API request every 2 seconds. I figured out the reason as `var status` is declared globally as `1` and even if I replace `status = result.check_status` . After the function context it will always remain 1 and go into if loop only; no matter what it receives from JSON response.

So, question is How would I be able to update `status` and clear the timeout (i.e go to the else part) if `result.check_status` is 0 (i.e {'check_status':2} as Response from API call) ??

Comment: The entire `if` logic only runs exactly once, when the page is loaded. If you want to run it again and again, you have to move it to the `success` callback (or put it in a function and call it from there.

Comment: It does move to success callback @Chris G

Comment: "it does move"...? No clue what you mean by that. Anyway, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do this:

```
var status = {{ check_status }};

function call_polling() {
    // polling request to API (async)
    success: function (result){
        status = result.check_status;
        if (status) setTimeout(call_polling, 2000);
    }
}

call_polling();
```

In short, as long as the response is `1`, a new timeout for the check is set.

Comment: Why you need to make status as global variable while you are using it inside the callback function only. Event initially assigned value is also not used

Comment: @HridayModi How do you know that? The OP obviously only posted relevant code, so what makes you think `status` isn't used elsewhere? That's in fact highly likely, given that the entire exercise would be pointless otherwise.

Comment: Exactly, If `status` is used at other places than it's wrong implementation as it will get overridden in API callback.

Comment: @ChrisG implementation answers what I needed.